# How can I switch users in NixOS?

Tags: nixos, sddm, bspwm

I'm using the BSPWM window manager in NixOS, and using home-manager to handle the session. SDDM is my display manager. I can log in just fine, but I don't know how to switch users. On Arch, TTY1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) always had SDDM running on it, so I could just press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and start a new session by logging in as a different user. But I don't know how to get that set up on Nix. Any ideas?

[My dotfiles are here, if they help to see how my setup is put together.](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/dotfiles/tree/minimal/dotfiles)